# Test ASP.NET WebAPI methods for exception logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, logging, error-logging

We have an `ASP.NET` `WebAPI` 2 project in our solution with a few controllers having methods which will log all exceptions that occurs to a text file. Each `WebAPI` method has `try...catch` block and there is some custom logic involved when logging the errors, so I want to quickly test all the methods of all controllers to check if the logs are generated in correct format in case any exception occurs. Can this be done by adding a test project to my solution? When calling the `WebAPI` method from the test class, the method that is called should throw and error and log it, can this be done? Are there any other alternatives to test this case?

Comment: Have a separate method that calls all methods with "wrong" arguments, where an exception is expected. Or what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

First, this sort of error logging should really be done in a global exception handler so you don't have repeat the same code over and over in your controllers.

Second, when it comes to logging, most of the time you should really only be testing that messages are logged, not the format of the messages (the logging class should have it's own unit tests).

Here's a good read on how to write a global handler:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

Just publish your WebAPI and create a console program to call all your methods in the api with your set of test parameters and you are going to get your txt file with your exceptions.
Automatize in some form your tests.
Use this link information to create unit tests: [Unit Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api)